# Oracle String concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute the below query, which pivots a table by passing the values to pivot in a variable. It has worked for other queries.

```
DECLARE
    cols VARCHAR2(30000);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(''''
                || agr_name
                || ''' as "'
                || agr_name
                || '"', ',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                agr_name
        )
    INTO cols
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                to_char(agr_name) AS agr_name
            FROM
                dat_skills
--            WHERE
--                ROWNUM < 400
        );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_dat_skills AS
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        dat_skills PIVOT (
            COUNT ( agr_name )
            FOR agr_name
            IN (]'||cols||q'[)
        )
    ]'
    ;
END;
```

But I'm getting the below error:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

If I execute the select distinct it retrieves 138 rows with a total length of 2777 characters of length.

```
WITH aux AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        to_char(agr_name) AS agr_name
    FROM
        dat_skills
)
SELECT
    count(1), sum(length(agr_name))
FROM
    aux
```

Is there any workaround I could take to bypass this restriction? Or something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong (except probably the calculation, because you have to add single quotes and "`as`" which is added to every value query returns), but `LISTAGG` has the upper limit set to 4000 characters.

What to do? Switch to `XMLAGG`. How? Like this:

```
SQL> SELECT LISTAGG (dname, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dname) AS r_listagg,
  2         --
  3         RTRIM (
  4            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, dname || ', ') ORDER BY dname).EXTRACT (
  5               '//text()'),
  6            ', ') r_xmalagg
  7    FROM dept
  8  /

R_LISTAGG
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R_XMALAGG
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING, OPERATIONS, RESEARCH, SALES
ACCOUNTING, OPERATIONS, RESEARCH, SALES


SQL>
```

Rewrite it so that it works for your tables & columns.

Comment: ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead  I'm getting this after rewriting my query with xmlagg

Comment: Also, I'm using the quotes and as "" because if I don't do that, the columns are not interpreted correctly. Not sure if there's any easier way to do this.

Comment: Try to put the result into a CLOB datatype variable (instead of VARCHAR2).

Comment: Error report -
ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 24
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead

Comment: This is what I'm now getting after defining cols as a clob

Comment: Could I reopen the question as the other question's answer is not working for me?